# Netsuite timetrack Duration field into a Workflow

Tags: netsuite

I would like to trigger an email when a new Time entry is created in Netsuite. Usually this can be easily accomplished through a Saved Search/Email but for Time searches, sending on Create is not available and already the topic of an enhancement request.

I've created a Workflow which will trigger upon Time entry create.  In order to use the time entry fields I first created Workflow Fields and then in State 1 populate those workflow fields with the values. Suiteanswers: Use SQL expressions in Send Email action via the Workflow Manager (ID: 21669)

I can map many of the fields like Customer:Project, Service Item from the Time entry into my Workflow.  I am stuck on mapping the Netsuite Duration field which according to the Records Browser is of a type "timetrack" ie 1:05.

I have tried it from the available field types, Date, Date/Time, Integer.  I'm now trying to populate is into a Text field but am stuck as to how to convert it from the timetrack record type into Text.

Have tried

```
TO_CHAR({hours})
CAST({hours} AS text)
```

I just want a field with the Duration that I can use in an email. :)

How could I achieve this affect? Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that somewhere along the track I over-complicated what was needed. In the end I just inserted {hours} into my email text box and it worked.  I can't explain why it didn't work initially.